# normalizing constant from kernel density in R

Tags: r, kernel-density, normalizing

How can I get the normalizing constant from a non-standard distribution. Ex:

```
x <- c(rnorm(500,10,1),rnorm(500,20,2),rnorm(500,35,1))
```

after using density in R

```
dens<-density(x,n=length(x),adjust=0.4)
```

Comment: do you mean the bandwidth?  `dens$bw`

Comment: I´m not sure, is it the bandwidth the same as the normalizing constant?

Comment: oh, I see what you mean now, the density is already normalized (or pretty close to it).   Check it out with `f <- approxfun(dens, yleft = 0, yright = 0); integrate(f, lower=min(x)-0.1, upper=max(x)+0.1)`.  So, the answer is 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of density() should be a proper probability density function, so the area under the curve returned by density() should already be 1.

Your example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rnorm(500,10,1), rnorm(500,20,2), rnorm(500,35,1))
dens <- density(x, n=length(x), adjust=0.4)
```

We can get an approximation of the area under the pdf by numerically integrating it:

```
install.packages("sfsmisc")
library(sfsmisc)
integrate.xy(dens$x, dens$y)
```

Which gives

```
[1] 1.000241
```

The area is indeed rather close to 1.

There are numerical accuracy issues however which may cause this area to deviate significantly from 1. They are discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/area-under-the-pdf-in-kernel-density-estimation-in-r) for example.